# Google Map APIs not working after adding bundle identifier - iOS

Tags: ios, bundle, google-places-api, identifier

I Google developer console I created an iOS key as below:
[image]

I want to restrict this key to one app only, so I "Edit allowed iOS application" add my bundle Id to it. My bundle Id is easily found in General tab of my project target as following:

[image]

I don't know if it is case-sensitive or not, but I copy exactly the identifier from there to add to the key. As you can see, it cannot be mistaken. I also followed Google's instruction, one bundle Identifier per line (I only input one line):

> Accept requests from an iOS application with one of the bundle
>   identifiers listed below (Optional) One bundle identifier per line.
>   Example: com.example.MyApp
>
> Or if you leave this blank, requests will be accepted from any iOS
>   application. Be sure to add bundle identifiers before using this key
>   in production.

This screen show that I enabled all necessary services, to be sure:

[image]

The problem with me is that, whenever I added a bundle identifier to the key, my app stops working. But then when I deleted it (now "Any application allowed" as in the picture), everything goes back to work fine.

Could anyone please tell me what could possible cause this?

UPDATE: To clarify more: When I add my bundle ID to the key in Developer Console, now I can still use nearby search in my app. But Autocomplete search and Google URL shortener have stopped working..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason Autocomplete stops working when you add an iOS Bundle ID is that `Google Places API Web Service` is specifically not designed for using on iOS. As a gentle hint, I suggest you poke around [Google Places API for iOS](https://developers.google.com/places/ios/) after Google I/O happens later this week. =)

Answer (score 5):

whatever request that is getting 403 should be sent with additional header `X-Ios-Bundle-Identifier`, where your bundle id should be set. This seems undocumented, I only found it through jumping between links, see [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-cloud-endpoints/I-u3sAUU3Ts/KewsToMMAwAJ)...

Answer (score 2):

I also ran into this issue and solved it by following @zhywu's answer above

The **Swift 5** code that leverages URLSession/URLSessionDataTask looks like this:

```
if var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: "https://www.googleapis.com/...") {
            ...
            guard let url = urlComponents.url else { return }

            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            request.setValue(Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier ?? "", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Ios-Bundle-Identifier")

            dataTask = defaultSession.dataTask(with: request) { ... }
            ...
}
```